# How to expose a custom serialized image field in Views in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views

I have added a custom image field to an already existing form which saves the details in DB as a BLOB object (serialized).

I am able to expose the serialized field itself in Views. I am also able to expose each key of the serialized data.

However, exposing the serialized image only shows the fid of the uploaded image.

How I do I expose it as a normal image field with all the image settings like display format, link this page to original content, etc.?

[image: Exposed Serialized Key in Views]

Any help with sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting, did you check if the fid indeed exists in file table?

Comment: Oh yes Jimmy, it does exist. In fact, if I expose the image field as a key of the serialized value in Views, it does show the fid. But just the fid is of no much use right? I need to render the image. So...I know I can use Views PHP and load the image but looking for a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: So what do you mean by **saves the details in DB as a BLOB object**. I don't understand what your case is...

Comment: Umm..its actually like this: I need to add fields to the Add Flag form (in Flag module). So, the details of Flags like  link/unlink text, roles, type of link to show..they are all wrapped in a serialized string and stored in DB in a column whose data type is BLOB..

Comment: a:18:{s:10:"flag_short";s:15:"Give this Badge";s:9:"flag_long";s:0:"";s:12:"flag_message";s:0:"";s:12:"unflag_short";s:12:"Remove Badge";s:11:"unflag_long";s:0:"";s:14:"unflag_message";s:0:"";s:18:"unflag_denied_text";s:0:"";s:9:"link_type";s:6:"toggle";s:6:"weight";i:-31;s:17:"badge_description";s:35:"<p>High Five Badge description.</p>";s:11:"badge_image";}